# How to cast Predicate<T> to Func<T, bool>

Tags: c#, linq, predicate, func

I have a problem trying to cast a `Predicate<T>` to `Func<T, bool>`. I have a method that accepts a `object[]` variable as argument:

```
protected abstract Predicate<TResults> PredicateFind(object[] values);
```

It works perfectly for `List.Find`:

```
protected TResults Find(params object[] values) => Resultados.Find(PredicateFind(values));
```

but trying to use it with `List.Any`:

```
protected TResults Any(params object[] values) => Resultados.Any(r => new Func<TResults, bool>(x => (bool)PredicateFind(values) == true));
```

gives:

```
CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.Predicate<TResults>' to 'bool'
```

Trying to change it to

```
protected TResults Any(params object[] values) => Resultados.Any(PredicateFind(values));
```

gives:

`CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Predicate<TResults>' to 'System.Function<TResults, bool>'`

And changing it to

```
protected TResults Any(params object[] values) => Resultados.Any(new Func<TResults, bool>(PredicateFind(values)));
```

gives

`CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'TResults'`

How should I call `Predicate(object[] values)` to be able to use it with `Any`?

Thank you

---

### EDIT

Finally the problem was in

```
protected TResults Any(params object[] values) => Resultados.Any(PredicateFind(values));
```

First I had to change the return type to `bool`

```
protected bool Any(params object[] values) => Resultados.Any(PredicateFind(values));
```

and second I had to change the argument to `r => PredicateFind(values).Invoke(r)`

```
protected bool Any(params object[] values) => Resultados.Any(r => PredicateFind(values).Invoke(r));
```

Now it's fixed.

Thank you all.

Comment: The [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) function iterates over all elements in the list and returns whether at least one of them matches a condition. Are you sure it's what you're trying to do? Your `PredicateFind` doesn't consider the list elements at all.

Comment: Can you tell us what you are actually trying to do with the Any method? I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish. Any doesn't return elements, it returns true or false.

Comment: I want to check if there is any TResults that satisfies a condition. The condition depends on the class that is implementing `protected abstract Predicate<TResults> PredicateFind(object[] values);`, but usually consists of checking a property of TResults contains or is equal to a value